# DBappender errors on play restart

Tags: playframework-2.0, slf4j, logback

I have a setup that records messages from a certain logger to DB. Here's my logger.xml's related component:

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
  <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
    <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logback</url>
    <user>ashishag</user>
    <password>password</password>
  </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

When I start the play server, DB appender works fine.

```
20:18:05,907 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
20:18:05,913 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DB]
20:18:05,994 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@8d2c5b - Driver name=PostgreSQL Native Driver
20:18:05,994 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@8d2c5b - Driver version=PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)
20:18:05,994 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@8d2c5b - supportsGetGeneratedKeys=true
```

It determines the driver name just fine.
However, when I save a file which causes play to compile the file and restart the server, the DB appender stops working.

```
20:21:29,183 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
20:21:29,183 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DB]
20:21:29,184 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@a80681 - Could not discover the dialect to use. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logback
        at java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logback
        at      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)


---snip--
20:21:29,195 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@44:14 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.lang.IllegalStateException: DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
        at java.lang.IllegalStateException: DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.db.DBAppenderBase.start(DBAppenderBase.java:62)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.start(DBAppender.java:92)
```

It looks like it fails to load the driver. (And perhaps that's why claims that getGeneratedKeys is not supported)

To summarize:
Start server:

> Driver name=PostgreSQL Native Driver
>
> Driver version=PostgreSQL 9.0
>
> JDBC4 (build 801) supportsGetGeneratedKeys=true

---

Restart server:
Claim that dialect not found(driver not found) and generatedKeys is not supported.

Would anyone know what's wrong?